# Docker and Scrapyrt - ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111]

Tags: docker, nginx, scrapy, python-requests

I need to open a background listener for Scrapy on my 'web' service in a Docker application, like so:

**task**:

```
@celery.task(
queue='scraping')
def scrape():
   params = {
          'spider_name': 'spider',
          'start_requests':True
            }
   response = requests.get('http://localhost:9080/crawl.json', params)
   return {'Status': 'Scraping completed!',
           'features': response}
```

My application runs a nginx reverse proxy server, and services are configured like so:

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
services:

  web:
    build:
      context: ./services/web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/web:/usr/src/app'

    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    depends_on:  
      - web-db
      - redis

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./services/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web
      - client
      - redis

 scrapyrt:
    image: vimagick/scrapyd:py3
    command: scrapyrt -i 0.0.0.0 -p 9080
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '9080:9080'
    volumes:
      - ./services/web:/usr/src/app
    working_dir: /usr/src/app/project/api
    depends_on:
      - web
```

Route in 'web' service sends request via scrape function using an async task:

```
@task_bp.route('/blogs/<user_id>', methods=['GET'])
      task = scrape.apply_async([user_id])
      response_object = {
            'status': 'success',
            'data': {
                'task_id': task.id,
                'results': task.get(),
            }
        }
      return jsonify(response_object), 202
```

**curl**:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5001/blogs/1 -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Twisted server seems to be working:

```
scrapyrt_1         | 2019-05-14 02:12:18+0000 [-] Log opened.
scrapyrt_1         | 2019-05-14 02:12:18+0000 [-] Site starting on 9080
scrapyrt_1         | 2019-05-14 02:12:18+0000 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7fcfdc977b70>
```

but celery log throws me the following error (Full traceback):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff217792a90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9080): Max retries exceeded with url: /crawl.json?spider_name=allmusic_smooth_tracks&start_requests=True (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff217792a90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/src/app/brandio/api/routes/background.py", line 904, in scrape_allmusic
    response = requests.get('http://localhost:9080/crawl.json', params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9080): Max retries exceeded with url: /crawl.json?spider_name=allmusic_smooth_tracks&start_requests=True (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff217792a90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Where is the service that calls `http://scrapy:9080/crawl.json`? Is it one of the services in the Docker Compose configuration?

Comment: yes. service 'web', which service 'scrapy' is dependent on.

Comment: what happens when you strip off celery and execute things manually ... in your setup is using celery optional ? if so I would get things working then add celery which looks like it sits atop everything

Comment: Restored. Feel free to add a comment about celery to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `localhost` with whatever name the target service has (`scrapyrt`).

Comment: thank you for the answer. this works, as long as `scrape()` is stripped off of Celery, as suggested by @Scott Stensland.